# Rectify virus in LAN

Tags: security, virus

I am sriram, we have a problem our company today, that is virus is attacked our LAN, so please give suggestion to rectify the virus.

It will effects

1. Taskbar is disabled
2. Network connection is not worked
3. cut,copy,post options are not worked
4. when our rigt click the pop menu does not opened

etc...

We checked different antiviruses but, we don't find out to rectify the problem.

Please help me......

Comment: Does your company have an IT department?

Comment: He probably is the it department

Answer (score 2):

Given the small amount of information available, it sounds like it would be best to rollback this machine to whatever the last backup was. If there is no backup (*shame*), you should boot the machine from a LiveCD, preferably Linux. There's [distros](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12) [made specially](http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/) for this that can make the process a lot less painful.

If the virus can't be removed by the tools on various LiveCDs then it's time to recover what uninfected files you can from the machine, and reinstall a clean copy of windows. A [LiveCD](http://www.knoppix.net/) is also good for this. Boot from the CD, transfer files via LAN or sneakerNet, and erase the hard drive using the CD. Once the coast is clear, reinstall windows on the machine.